# how to update jenkins build file Automatically

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I am trying to setup jenkins for a project in my company. We have TFS as Source and version control. The jenkins is installed on separate server where I have given project.sln file as *MSBuild Build File* . We are able to achieve integration where check-in in TFS triggres a build **but** every time there is a new file we have to manually copy the changes to build server or else build would fail. Is there anyway  to update the build file and code base at build server automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use service hooks provided by TFS